# Time complexity: Findning the mode of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, go, time-complexity, big-o

Being apart of a challange for beginners, I would like to know if my algorithm is indeed `O(n)` as I intended it to be.

The idea is simple, I'm given the task to create an algorithm that finds the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of an integer array. The only catch was that if two integers in the array had the same multiplicity, the mode would be the lesser integer.

I've seen other algorithms around that do the job in `O(n logn)`, however in the challange description it was mentioned that it could be done in `O(n)`.

First of, I created a hash table that stores each integer that is found in the array with a key that represents it's own multiplicity.

If we have an element with the same multiplicity as the maximum multiplicity we check if the new element is less than mode. If it is, the new element becomes the new mode.

I chose Golang for my implementation.

```
func mode(input []int) (int, error) {

    // Error handeling.
    if len(input) == 0 {
        return -1, errors.New("can't find the mode of an empty array")
    }

    // Initilize a hashtable with key representing the multiplicities.
    m := make(map[int]int)

    mode := 0

    // The biggest multiplicity.
    max := 0

    for _, elem := range input {
        m[elem]++
        if m[elem] > max {
            max = m[elem]
            mode = elem
        }
        if m[elem] == max && mode > elem {
            mode = elem

        }
    }
    return mode, nil
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Adrian: From the OP question: "I would like to know if my algorithm is indeed O(n) as I intended it to be."

Comment: @Adrian: Like I stated at the very beginning of my post. Is my algorithm linear?

Answer (score 4):

More or less. The map insertions and lookups are somewhere between O(1) and O(log n), where *n* is the number of elements in the *map*, not in the input array. So your result will be close to O(n), or more accurately somewhere between O(n) and O(n log m) where *m* is the number of unique entries in the input.

Comment: Should not the maximum possible complexity be considered? In that case all entries in the input are unique. So the complexity should be `O(n log n)`?

Comment: It should be considered, which is why I noted it, I just gave more detail. To clarify, the *theoretical worst-case* performance would be O(n log n), while the real-world performance would remain very close to O(n).

Comment: By consider I mean it should be assumed it is that value. There is no `m` in complexity theory. The measurement of complexity is one value. There is no range.

Comment: I gave a practical answer. If you'd like to give a theory answer you're free to post your own.

Comment: That is alright. Your reasoning is sound and your answer is almost perfect, but not quite correct. Just wanted to point that out.